# Change background image of div on mouseover of a link

Tags: jquery, html, background-image

## What I want to achieve

I want the background image of div to change on the mouseover of a link within the said div.

## Example

```
<div id="container">
     <a href="" id="linktomouseover"></a>
</div>
```

## What I've tried

I've tried swapping the background image using jQuery:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

jQuery('#linktomouseover').mouseover(function()
{
jQuery('#container').css("background-image", "url(bg-b.png)");
});

</script>
```

Can anyone advise me on what I'm missing?

## Solution

```
<style> 
#container{ 
width:100%; 
height:100%; 
background-image:url(http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/thumblarge_536/12838649102C1cO5.jpg); 
} 
</style> 

<div id="container"><br><br> 
<a href="" id="linktomouseover">hover</a> 
</div>

<script> 
jQuery('#linktomouseover').hover(function() 
{ 
jQuery('#container').css("background-image", 
"url(http://static4.depositphotos.com/1011237/285/i/450/dep_2853473-Background-for-your-web-store.jpg)
"); 
}).mouseleave(function(){
jQuery('#container').css("background-image", "url(http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/thumblarge_536/12838649102C1cO5.jpg)"); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

missing id=

```
<div id="container">
```

not

```
<div="container">
```

and also switch .click() with .hover() as link says

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/31e7b/6

```
<style> 
#container{ 
        width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background-image:url(http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/thumblarge_536/12838649102C1cO5.jpg); 
} 
</style> 
<div id="container"><br><br> 
     <a href="" id="linktomouseover">hover</a> 
</div> 
<script> 
jQuery('#linktomouseover').hover(function() 
{ 
    jQuery('#container').css("background-image", "url(http://static4.depositphotos.com/1011237/285/i/450/dep_2853473-Background-for-your-web-store.jpg)"); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: It wasn't a reason for deletion :) But there are more errors I see :p

Comment: click? i think you mean mouseover or am i missing something?

Comment: @ChristianSmorra: whooops, mouseover, yes

Comment: Thanks for the example. It done the trick. I forget to mention that I needed to restore the original background image on mouseleave. I added my finished code to the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the solution, but you are currently not running your code after the dom-model is loaded, which probably means that jQuery('#linktomouseover') returns nothing.

Try this:

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    // Your code here
});
</script>
```

Also, if you would like to have this effect for more than one link, you can do it like this;

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="linktomouseover">link</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a class="linktomouseover">link</a>
</div>
```

js:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.linktomouseover').mouseover(function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().css('background-image', "url('bg-b.png')");
    });
});
```